# Getting deployment failure due to go_router package in flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

I am getting deployment failure due to go_router pkg.  Here the error.

[91mTarget dart2js failed: Exception: /root/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/go_router-3.1.1/lib/src/go_router.dart:22:44:
Step #0 - "docker-build": Error: The class 'NavigatorObserver' can't be used as a mixin because it isn't a mixin class nor a mixin.
Step #0 - "docker-build": class GoRouter extends ChangeNotifier with NavigatorObserver

I am getting is from today only.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hi Subodh, were you able to resolve this issue? Having same issue, not sure how to fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this same issue when trying to deploy an app created through Flutterflow. I managed to fix it by downgrading the version of Flutter I'm using to 3.7.0